# Materializecss Date Picker only days in the past

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, materialize

I am trying to make a input field for the users birthday. For this I would like them to only select years in the past.

How do I achieve this? I tried entering a negative number in the `selectYears` property but no luck.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rpu61tf2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col s12">
   <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
   <input id="birthday" value="{{ user.birthday }}" type="date" name="birthday" class="datepicker">
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate(
{
   selectMonths: true,
   selectYears: -100
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear( d.getFullYear() - 100 );
$('.datepicker').pickadate(
{
   selectMonths: true,
   selectYears: d,
   max: new Date()
});
```

This will actually give full list of 100 past years.

Comment: you can just set selectYears to 100 or 101, the first two lines aren't needed. The max value property takes care of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you set the year:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear( d.getFullYear() - 100 );
$('.datepicker').pickadate(
{
   selectMonths: true,
   selectYears: true,
   min: d,
   max: new Date()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpu61tf2/3/

You set `selectYears: true` when you want to allow your users to select the years from a drop down

Comment: perhaps something has changed, downto 2008 you can select